# Facebook login: store data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I let my users login easily using facebook login after this login is succesfull the user has to be redirected to the index.html page and it's data should be stored in the database.

I can login and store the data seperatly but how can I combine these two together?

**FACEBOOK**

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'myid',
    cookie     : true,  

    xfbml      : true,  
    version    : 'v2.3'
  });


  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';

    });
  }
```

**ANGULAR**

```
login = angular.module('login', []);
login.controller("loginuser",function($scope,$http,$timeout){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    var username = $scope.name; //SHOULD BE THE USERS NAME AFTER FB LOGIN
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'login/' + username).then(function (results) {    
            //user added if not in database
            //+redirect to index.html
        });

    });
```

So after the fb login is succesfull the angular has to be called so the user data from fb can be stored in the db and the user gets redirected to the index.html page, how can this be accomplished?